# Correct way of storing a list of related values in Database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

Let's say I have the following scenario.
A database of `LocalLibrary` with two tables `Books` and `Readers`

```
| BookID|  Title   | Author | 
-----------------------------
|  1    | "Title1" | "John" | 
|  2    | "Title2" | "Adam" | 
|  3    | "Title3" | "Adil" |
------------------------------
```

And the readers table looks like this.

```
| UserID| Name | 
-----------------
|  1    | xy   L  
|  2    | yz   | 
|  3    | xz   | 
----------------
```

Now, lets say that user can create a list of books that they read (a bookshelf, that strictly contains books from above authors only i.e authors in our Db). So, what is the best way to represent that bookshelf in Database.

My initial thought was a comma separated list of `BookID`in `Readers`  table. But it clearly sounds awkward for a relational Db and I'll also have to split it every time I display the list of users' books. Also, when a user adds a new book to shelf, there is no way of checking if it already exists in their shelves except to split the comma-separated list and and compare the IDs of two. Deleting is also not easy.

So, in one line, the question is how does one appropriately models situations like these.
I have not done anything beyond simple SELECTs and INSERTs in MySQL. It would be much helpful if you could describe in simpler terms and provide links for further reading.

Please comment If u need some more explanation.

Comment: This is a textbook case of a many-to-many database relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely forget the idea about a comma separated list of books to add to the Readers table. It will be unsearchable and very clumsy. You need a third table that join the Books table and the Readers table. Each record in this table represent a reader reading a book.

```
Table ReaderList
--------------------
UserID | BookID    |
--------------------
```

You get a list of books read by a particular user with

```
select l.UserID, r.Name, l.BookID, b.Title, b.Author
from ReaderList l left join Books b on l.BookID = b.BookID
     left join Readers r on l.UserID = r.UserID
where l.UserID = 1
```

As you can see this pattern requires the use of the keyword JOIN that bring togheter data from two or more table. You can read more about JOIN in this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)
If you want, you could enhance this model adding another field to the ReaderList like the ReadingDate

Comment: So, every row in this `ReaderList` is representing a relationship, it also doesn't seem to have traditional <tableName>ID column. Also, +1 for `readed` in "You get a list of books..". That's syntax error :) and for enhancing tip.

Comment: Well, syntax error apart, yes, this is the best way to address the relationship. A reader reads zero or n books, a book is read by zero or n readers.